# Swift array initialization

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift.

Have a question for initialization of array.

AFAIK there are few ways to initialize way.

I understand for this

```
let arr1: [String] = []
```

But this syntax is hard to understand

```
let arr2 = [String]()
```

Could you please explain for the last syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: Read throught this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you are explicitly stating the type of the constant as `[String]` and then initializing it. Hence, you can provide empty braces and compiler would know that you need a String empty array.

In the second case, you are initializing it and letting compiler infer the type of the constant. Because, compiler needs to know the type for inferring, you have to explicitly mark the type while initializing i.e. `[String]()`.

Comment: Then what is () ?

Comment: [String] is an array of strings, while [(String)] is an array of tuples which contain 1 string.There should be no difference – this is a glitch somewhere in Xcode or Swift if you see [(String)]. In theory, all variables are single element tuples

Comment: This is like new in other languages. To create any object in Swift, you can use ().